# Derivatives - Basic Question

Tags: calculus

Can two different functions have the same derivative?
Given two function D[f[x],x] = D[y[x],x]
Must f[x] = y[x]?
Can there be no other possibility?

Comment: They can both be constants, or $f(x) = c x$, $f(t) = c t$ or other similar choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have two different functions with the same derivative, but they must differ by a constant.  That is,

> Let $f,g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be differentiable functions. If for all $x$: $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}g(x)$, then $$f(x)=g(x)+C$$ for some constant $C\in\mathbb R$

This follows from the fact that $f(x)-g(x)$ is constant (over any open interval) if and only if $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)-g(x))=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider any differentiable function $h(x)$ and then look at 
$$
f(x):=h(x)+C_1, y(t):=h(t)+C_2
$$